# Liferay: unable adding portlet from Dockbar

Tags: javascript, liferay, portlet, control-panel

I am using Liferay 6.1.1 GA2 bundled with Tomcat 7.0.23.
I am not able to add portlet onto the Liferay page using "add" button

in the firebug console i see this error: TypeError: **portletBound** is null from the **portlet.js** file.

If if run the debugger, I see that var portletBound is NULL in this function

```
var addPortletReturn = function(html) {
var container = placeHolder.get('parentNode');
var portletBound = A.Node.create('<div></div>');
portletBound.plug(A.Plugin.ParseContent);
portletBound.setContent(html);
portletBound = portletBound.get('firstChild');
var id = portletBound.attr('id');
```

and than I see only a gif Image and nothing happend.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution: in the portal.property json.service.auth.token.enabled was set to TRUE,
after setting it to FALSE, all works fine.